# how to show local notification only in background

Tags: ios, notifications, local

Iam trying to detect a beacon ,and when the beacon is in range irrespective of whether app in foreground or background local notification is shown,how can i show the notification only when app is in background and no notification in foreground?

Comment: When app is in foreground, didReceiveLocalNotification is the callback. Do nothing in it I believe, and the user won't know if any UILocalNotification has been received

Answer (score 2):

Use iOS7 background fetch delegate.
Implement the following delegate in the AppDelegate then post your local notification

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
// Post local notification
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel the notification when applicationDidEnterForeground: